# Reactjs: How to convert typescript class to functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Here I am converting the typescript class component to functional components but facing some issues I don't know how to fix. Please give me a solution to fix this issue.

[image]

class component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { ReactMultiEmail } from "react-multi-email";
import "react-multi-email/style.css";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  width: "500px",
  border: "1px solid #eee",
  background: "#f3f3f3",
  padding: "25px",
  margin: "20px"
};

interface IProps {}
interface IState {
  emails: string[];
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  state = {
    emails: []
  };

  render() {
    const { emails } = this.state;
    console.log("emails", emails)

    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <h3>react-multi-email</h3>
        <ReactMultiEmail
          placeholder="Input your Email Address"
          emails={emails}
          // onFocus={}
          onChange={(_emails: string[]) => {
            console.log("_email", _emails)
            this.setState({ emails: _emails });
          }}
          getLabel={(
            email: string,
            index: number,
            removeEmail: (index: number) => void
          ) => {
            return (
              <div data-tag key={index}>
                {email}
                <span data-tag-handle onClick={() => removeEmail(index)}>
                  ×
                </span>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
          
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

funcional component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { ReactMultiEmail } from "react-multi-email";
import "react-multi-email/style.css";


const styles = {
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    width: "500px",
    border: "1px solid #eee",
    background: "#f3f3f3",
    padding: "25px",
    margin: "20px"
  };

interface IProps {}
interface IState {
emails: string[];
  }

export const Email = (props:any) => {
    const [emails, setEmail] = React.useState([])
   
    return (
        <div style={styles}>
          <h3>react-multi-email</h3>
          <ReactMultiEmail
            placeholder="Input your Email Address"
            emails={emails}
            // onFocus={}
            onChange={(_emails: string[]) => {
              console.log("_email", _emails)
              setEmail({ _emails });
            }}
            getLabel={(
              email: string,
              index: number,
              removeEmail: (index: number) => void
            ) => {
              return (
                <div data-tag key={index}>
                  {email}
                  <span data-tag-handle onClick={() => removeEmail(index)}>
                    ×
                  </span>
                </div>
              );
            }
          }
            
          />
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    
}
```

I am a beginner in react js so I don't know if the right way of conversion or not please share valuable suggestions.

Comment: Show the error you are encountering. My guess is though, that you have set initial state to an empty array, but your first `setState` call is an object {_emails}. Set the type of your state variable explicitly `useState<>()`, and all else should follow.

Comment: Please if possible, try to provide your class example on a live code editor like [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-typescript-nkly1), that will be much easy for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten everything right, just need to make some small tweaks to the types.

The default type for `useState` is `never`. The error you're getting is a side-effect of this.

[image: Image attached in the question]

To fix this you need to set the type for the `useState`

```
const [emails, setEmail] = React.useState<Array<string>>([])
```

Check this codesandbox out as well -> https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-neco-5jmdjg?file=/src/App.tsx